# ZendFramework 2 - How to define a constant in a local configuration to be used in module.config.php

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have several instances of the same platform for different people.

Some of them have different translation files than others according to their specific requests.

For the moment, the files have different names and we distinguish them by the pattern in the module.config.php.

The problem is that we have to update and replace the module.config.php every time we update the code (with GIT) to change the pattern according to the client.

Is there a way to define a constant in a *.local.php file and to be able to access it in module.config.php with ZF2 ?

Thank you in advance for your help!

> Update : Thanks to @delboy1978uk.
>
> You can use environment variables either in (for Apache at least) the system-wide apache.conf or httpd.conf, in the virtual host or in the .htaccess file. It will then be accessible by getenv()

Comment: We use environment variables in our .local.php files, use `getenv()`

Comment: You can try set constant in config/global.php

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks for your answer too, but it doesn't work either. 

It may be something specific about the framework, in the order of the files loading. Because in each of thoses ways I can retrieve it on the views.

Comment: @delboy1978uk Oh oh, thank you a lot. I've first tried to defined it in the global file but it didn't work. I then tried it in Apache's configuration and the magic happened.